# Maven: How do Dependencies in no profile work?

Tags: maven

I have dependencies outside any profile, and also they are repeated inside each profile, with different scopes. So...

1. When running with a profile, I guess the dependencies declared in the profile are used.. right?
2. And when running with no profile the ones declared inside no profile are used ?
3. If a dependency is declared in no profile but in the main section, when running with a specific profile, that dependency is used right ? So dependencies that are used always should not be declared inside profiles right?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm a little confused.

Comment: Have you checked via `mvn help:effective-pom` ? Apart from that declaring a dependency in a profile is not really good idea. Can you give an example why you do that?

Comment: Well actually I didn't do anything, I'm trying  to make an existent pom better. But an example would be, to declare as provided certain dependencies in the jboss profile because jboss provides them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after playing a bit that night I got the answers:
 1. Yes
 2. Yes
 3. Yeap